# Loop counter in Java API

Tags: java, performance, loops

All,

While going through some of the files in Java API, I noticed many instances where the looping counter is being decremented rather than increment. i.e. in `for` and `while` loops in [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. Though this might be trivial, is there any significance for decrementing the counter rather than increment?

Comment: I looked to http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html and only saw decrements being used in lastIndexOf, which makes sense. Can you point us to the source you are looking at?

Comment: This is strange. I am looking at the source code of JDK 1.6 and the equals() method is different than the link you have mentioned. I am not able to locate those lines in the link you sent.

Comment: @Synesso @darkie15: That appears to be the Apache Harmony version of `String`.

Comment: @ColinD: No, I believe. Its because the link provided by `Synesso` is of Java 6 source.

Comment: There was an answer referring to Peter Norvig: while the answer is gone one can never go wrong with Norvig so I've linked it here http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#slow. Bear in mind this is circa 1998

Comment: @Adeel: No, the source provided by Synesso is very clearly Apache Harmony, given the Apache license and the imports like `org.apache.harmony.kernel.vm.VM`. The Java 6 source I looked at (Oracle's) shows looping down with `--` in `equals`, like darkie15 mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've compiled two simple loops with eclipse 3.6 (java 6) and looked at the byte code whether we have some differences. Here's the code:

```
for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){}
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){}
```

And this is the bytecode:

```
// 1st for loop - decrement 2 -> 0
 0 iconst_2
 1 istore_1      // i:=2
 2 goto 8
 5 inc 1 -1      // i+=(-1)
 8 iload_1
 9 ifge 5        // if (i >= 0) goto 5

// 2nd for loop - increment 0 -> 2
12 iconst_0 
13 istore_1      // i:=0
14 goto 20
17 inc 1 1       // i+=1
20 iload_1
21 iconst 2
22 if_icmple 17  // if (i <= 2) goto 17
```

The increment/decrement operation should make no difference, it's either `+1` or `+(-1)`. The main difference in this typical(!) example is that in the first example we *compare to 0* (`ifge i`), in the second we *compare to a value* (`if_icmple i 2`). And the comaprision is done in each iteration. So *if* there is any (slight) performance gain, I think it's because it's less costly to compare with 0 then to compare with other values. So I guess it's not incrementing/decrementing that makes the difference but the *stop criteria*.

So if you're *in need* to do some micro-optimization on source code level, try to write your loops in a way that you compare with zero, otherwise keep it as readable as possible (and incrementing is *much easier* to understand):

```
 for (int i =  0; i <= 2; i++) {}  // readable
 for (int i = -2; i <= 0; i++) {}  // micro-optimized and "faster" (hopefully)
```

**Addition**

Yesterday I did a very basic test - just created a 2000x2000 array and populated the cells based on calculations with the cell indices, once counting from `0->1999` for both rows and cells, another time backwards from `1999->0`. I wasn't surprised that both scenarios had a similiar performance (185..210 ms on my machine).

So **yes**, there is a difference on byte code level (eclipse 3.6) but, hey, we're in 2010 now, it doesn't seem to make a significant difference nowadays. So again, and using Stephens words, "don't waste your time" with this kind of optimization. Keep the code readable and understandable.

Comment: Ummm ... looking at the bytecode is not particularly instructive.  What you really need to do is to do a thorough analysis of the native code emitted by the JIT compiler.

Comment: @Stephen C - I disagree it is not instructive, it gives us an upper bound on any performance delta. Assuming we knew the timings of `iconst`, `ifge` and `if_icmple`, and that the JIT isn't going to make anything run *slower*, we could say that one version would be less than X% slower than the other.

Comment: Cool! I even did not think about this problem in this aspect. Thank you.

Comment: @CurtainDog - Your argument doesn't hold water.  You assume that each bytecode is translated into a fixed sequence of native code instructions, and that you can just add up the timings.  In fact, the optimizations performed mean that the mapping of bytecodes to native code will be highly context dependent ... and non-sequential.

Comment: @Stephen C - What I'm saying is the "Worst Case Scenario" is that each bytecode is translated into a fixed sequence of instructions, etc, etc. This is a useful piece of info to know as it allows us to prioritize where we spend our time optimising. And, when coding back in '98, the loop counter was evidently a good place to optimise.

Comment: @CurtainDog - *"This is a useful piece of info to know as it allows us to prioritize where we spend our time optimising."* -- Umm, only if you plan to waste your time.  The "worst case" doesn't tell you anything about what the optimizer will actually do.  For instance, it might *optimize the whole block away*.  Like I said above, if you really want do a decent job of hand optimizing, you need to look at the generated native code.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, benchmark.

```
public class IncDecTest
{
    public static void main(String[] av)
    {
        long up = 0;
        long down = 0;
        long upStart, upStop;
        long downStart, downStop;
        long upStart2, upStop2;
        long downStart2, downStop2;

        upStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ )
        {
            up++;
        }
        upStop = System.currentTimeMillis();

        downStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( long j = 100000000; j > 0; j-- )
        {
            down++;
        }
        downStop = System.currentTimeMillis();

        upStart2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( long k = 0; k < 100000000; k++ )
        {
            up++;
        }
        upStop2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        downStart2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( long l = 100000000; l > 0; l-- )
        {
            down++;
        }
        downStop2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        assert (up == down);

        System.out.println( "Up: " + (upStop - upStart));
        System.out.println( "Down: " + (downStop - downStart));     
        System.out.println( "Up2: " + (upStop2 - upStart2));
        System.out.println( "Down2: " + (downStop2 - downStart2));
    }
}
```

With the following JVM:

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)
```

Has the following output (ran it multiple times to make sure the JVM was loaded and to make sure the numbers settled down a little).

```
$ java -ea IncDecTest
Up: 86
Down: 84
Up2: 83
Down2: 84
```

These all come extremely close to one another and I have a feeling that any discrepancy is a fault of the JVM loading some code at some points and not others, or a background task happening, or simply falling over and getting rounded down on a millisecond boundary.

While at one point (early days of Java) there might have been some performance voodoo to be had, it seems to me that that is no longer the case.

Feel free to try running/modifying the code to see for yourself.

Comment: While I don't _think_ that the reality would be much different than this, do be aware that this isn't good microbenchmark... starting with the fact that it uses `currentTimeMillis()` rather than `nanoTime()` for timing (read the Javadoc for those methods). Also take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that this is a result of Sun engineers doing a whole lot of profiling and micro-optimization, and those examples that you found are the result of that.  It is also possible that they are the result of Sun engineers "optimizing" based on deep knowledge of the JIT compilers ... or based on shallow / incorrect knowledge / voodoo thinking.

It is possible that these sequences:

- are faster than the increment loops,
- are no faster or slower than increment loops, or
- are slower than increment loops for the latest JVMs, and the code is no longer optimal.

Either way, **you should not emulate this practice in your code**, unless thorough profiling with the latest JVMs demonstrates that:

- your code really will benefit from optimization, and
- the decrementing loop really is faster than the incrementing loop for your particular application.

And even then, you *may* find that your carefully hand optimized code is less than optimal on other platforms ... and that you need to repeat the process all over again.

These days, it is generally recognized that the best first strategy is to write simple code and leave optimization to the JIT compiler.  Writing complicated code (such as loops that run in reverse) may actually foil the JIT compiler's attempts to optimize.