# Are backward loops faster in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Loop counter in Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181941/loop-counter-in-java-api)
>   [Which of these pieces of code is faster in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656506/which-of-these-pieces-of-code-is-faster-in-java)

```
for(int i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {}
for(int i = 1; i < 100001; i++) {}
```

Which one is faster?I read that first for loop is faster.is it true?Then how it become faster than other?please help.

Comment: How about trying it out?

Comment: This is really interesting :) PHP provides such a result too (most of the time): http://codepad.org/BmxDGE9D

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares - surely you could have found a better Q&A to link to.  The accepted answer to the one you linked to is (IMO) plain wrong.

Comment: And yeah, it is clearly a duplicate as stated by Maurício Linhares.

Comment: Both can be optimized away since nothing happens in the loop. As soon as something happens there, the time spend just for for looping becomes negligible.

Comment: See this one for a better answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656506/which-of-these-pieces-of-code-is-faster-in-java

Comment: @StephenC Edited the question with this better link.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius - because it makes the mistake of thinking that you can infer the speed of code from looking at the bytecodes.  In fact, the JIT compiler is quite likely to produce native code that is sufficiently different that bytecode-based reasoning cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell which of the two is faster.

If all you provide is a snippet of Java code, all we have to go on is the Java Language Specification. Since the Java Language Specification never mentions any timing aspects there's no way to answer the question.

It is similar to asking your math teacher, *"Which is faster to compute, 17+17 or 17*17?"* Your math teacher will just stare at you and at best respond with something like, *"are you using pen and paper or a pocket calculator?"*

Comment: Really? Can't we just time it?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman I think aioobe is saying that the result could be JVM dependent.

Comment: @assylias... if you even decide to target bytecode that is.