# Why loop in descending order is faster than increasing order?

Tags: java, performance, loops

I saw this problem from some blog. The following two loops are given, the question is which one is faster.

```
for(int i = 100000; i > 0; i--) {}
for(int i = 1; i < 100001; i++) {}
```

Why the first one is faster than the second one?

Comment: Benchmarks or it didn't happen.

Comment: The differences, if any, would be measured in nanoseconds.

Comment: It probably depends more on what you are doing in the loops than the loops themselves. If you're going down this micro optimisation route did you know that `++i` is faster than `i++`?

Comment: @Bohemian which means that in Java they wouldn't be measurable due to the 15ms clock resolution.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181941/loop-counter-in-java-api

Comment: @boris huh? See [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On some processors in code generated by some compilers the first one *could be* faster because the value is compared to zero. As @DeadMG notes it applies, for example, to x86 processors before 1985.

But it is:

- a **premature optimization**, don't change first line to the second only because of this reason!   Donald Knuth once said and I totally agree with him

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil.

- a **non-portable** optimization - it works faster only on some specific processors in some specific cases! And with a high probability it will work not just the same but even slower on other architectures.

You are warned.

Comment: To be more specific, this has only been the case on, for example, x86 processors before 1985. So you might want to be a lot more specific about what processors you think this applies to.

Comment: And it's a carry over from C, where you can code the condition as simply `i`, ie `for(int i = 100000; i; i--)`